# How to create 2d array in java with scanner input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to create 2D array in java with given scanner input.

```
1 3
2
3
-1
```

and the result will be like that `[[1,2],[3],[3],[-1]]`.

I tried with following one unfortunately, it was still not correct. Please let me know how to do it, thanks.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nodes[][] = new int[4][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            nodes[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read an entire line. Then split the line on space. The size of the array is the number of items. Create the sub-array using that length:

```
int nodes[][] = new int[4][];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    String[] s = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    nodes[i] = new int[s.length];
    for(int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
        nodes[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(s[j]);
    }
}
```